# I want to convert my python code to powershell for windows host

Tags: python, powershell

**I want to convert my python code to powershell for my windows machine can someone help me please .**
*My python code:*

```
 def AddExtension(self, extension):
        if extension not in self.extensions:
            self.extensions.append(extension)
            pass
        pass

    pass
```

*my test to convert my python 3 script to powershell and my code is underline and i dont know why*

```
class Item
{
    [String] $name
    [String] $path
    [String] $modification

    Item([String] $name, [String] $path,[String] $modification)
    {
        $this.name = $name
        $this.path = $path
        $this.modification= $modification
    }

  
}

class Dossier:Item {
    [String] $name
    [String] $path
    [String] $modification
    [String] $creation
    [string] $extension
    [String] $pathBakcup
    
  
    Dossier([String] $name, [String] $path,[String] $modification,[String]$creation,[String]$extension,[String]$pathBakcup)
    {
        $this.name = $name
        $this.path = $path
        $this.modification= $modification
        $this.creation=$creation
        $this.extension=$extension
        $pathBakcup
    }

    function AddExtension {
        param (
            $extension
        )
        if ($extension -NOT $this.$extension) {
            $this.$extension.append($extension)
            
        }
       
}
```

Comment: Nice, where are you having trouble converting the code *yourself*?(;

Comment: yep, i don't know how to do :(

Comment: i do this and i have an error

Comment: Strings in .Net (and therefore Powershell) are immutable.  There is no `Append()` method of the string class in .Net, so that won't work. However, it's not clear to me what you expect `$this.$extension` to represent. Did you mean that, or did you mean `$this.extension`? My guess is that you probably want something like `$this.extention += $extension`. Truthfully, though, it looks like you're re-implementing `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: `$extension -NOT $this.$extension` has the wrong operator. `-not` is the boolean NOT, and it's unary (one-sided). You can't put an operand on the left hand side of the  `-not` operator. You probably want the not equal operator `$extension -ne $this.$extension`.

Comment: thanks you it work now, it is appreciate